# How do i define a second environment.rb file in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, environment-variables

My default environment.rb is overflowing, and i would like to have a separate file that works exactly the same way. How can I do so?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely adding things to the environment file that should be in an initializer. Check the config/initializers directory for some examples of what to put in there. That should allow you to break things up and make everything more organized.

Comment: Interesting! what should be in the initializer and what should be in environment? What is the "proper rails" way?

Comment: I usually use the environment.rb file for settings that are already in there such as `config.gem ...`. Anything else that's not specific to an environment goes in an initializer. http://ryandaigle.com/articles/2007/2/23/what-s-new-in-edge-rails-stop-littering-your-evnrionment-rb-with-custom-initializations

Answer (score 1):

Rails actually uses `eval` to load the special environment files such as *config/environments/development.rb*. This is the code it uses:

```
eval(IO.read(configuration.environment_path), binding, configuration.environment_path)
```

You could define a method such as `load_more_environment` like this:

```
def load_more_environment(path)
  eval(IO.read(path), binding, path)
end
```

The first argument to `eval` is just the code you want to load and it will be executed within the current `binding`. The third argument will be used to report syntax errors in the file.

Comment: This is fascinating. Thanks! =)